# How to initialize/start a custom clock program with windows boot?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, vb.net

I have developed a windows based clock program using C#,which has all clock functions like:

1. Show time in Digital/Analog Format.
2. Set up Alarm.

I want its service to start with windows boot up, so that I don't have to manually start it every time I logon to Windows.

I would like to know how do i put that service in start up?

For Example: I want the service "ClockService.exe" to run with windows start up, kindly let me know how do I do it.

Comment: So, you didnt read your last version of this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7064189?? Did you read the links given to you?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to initialize/start a custom clock program with windows boot?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7064189/how-to-initialize-start-a-custom-clock-program-with-windows-boot)

Comment: @BugFinder: Yeah I read the links given in my last closed question which is not the exact question and it is closed so I updated it with a new post.

Comment: OK, and what have you read about writing and installing services?

Comment: @BugFinder:There is nothing any link about writing and installing services. They posted a link of Jon Skeet for how to post a question or a blog.

Comment: @PowRoy:Both are my post as your posted link is closed and after update that question also I am not able to reopen it so I posted this question again.

Comment: I guess GOOGLE was too hard to find? There are numerous articles on writing services,  most people wont do your work for you. As you're not going to try. I vote to close this one too

Comment: I viewed most of the website where they were saying to go for a Windows Service Application, then one of my colleague told me to register my binaries with the Service control manager, so that I don't have to manually start my process, automatically it will run every time when I logon to the system.

Comment: I would not mind if StackOverflow, before allowing someone to ask his or her first question, would ask to confirm that you read Jon Skeet's  article. I guess the most used word in comments is "explain yourself"

Comment: Have I ever mentioned before that Windows Services cannot show a UI? Pretty sure I did, in the last question you asked on exactly this same topic.

Answer (score 3):

There is no point in you writing this application as a Windows Service because services cannot show any type of user interface. That means that users will not be able to see the clock face!

You would be better off putting a shortcut to your application into the Startup folder of the user/users who would like to run this program (that way when they log onto Windows, your application will start automatically).

You can find the location to the Startup folder programatically using the following code:

```vb
'All users startup folder
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonStartMenu)

'Currently logged on user's start-up folder
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.StartMenu)
```

Comment: That's not the only reason you shouldn't write this as a service. The *real* reason is because Windows Services **cannot** show a user interface. A startup application is the correct solution.